# Servo motor swinging back to 0°

Tags: servo

I just got my arduino and servo. But my servo may be acting strangely.

Whenever I tell the servo to go somewhere it keeps going to 0 than to that position and stops after 10-15 seconds or more.

This is the code used in this video

```
#include <Servo.h> 

    Servo myservo;

    void setup() 
    { 
      myservo.attach(11);
      myservo.write(50);
    } 

    void loop() 
    { 
    }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsikknT7z6g

It is connected like this:

Ground from Arduino to breadboard row 3

Ground from external power supply to breadboard row 3

Ground from SERVO to breadboard row 3

Power supply positive to servo VCC

Servo signal to pin 11

Comment: how is this being powered?

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

    Servo myservo;

    void setup() 
    { 
      myservo.attach(11);

    } 

    void loop() 
    { 
        delay(2000);
        myservo.write(50);
        while(1);
    }
```

and let us know.
But more important: disconnect the servo +5V wire from Arduino and use another power supplier!!!